# Overload templated class member function using enable_if_t

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I am trying to implement a class and overload its templated member functions through `enable_if`.

```
class Foo {
public:

  template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
  void do() {}

  template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
  void do() {}

};
```

Apparently the idea is to separate the instantiation exclusively of `T` with respect to arithmetic types. However, the compiler complains about `template <class T, class> void do()` cannot be overloaded. How exactly this can happen? What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: There must be a gazillion dupes out there... default template argument is not part of the signature. Put it in the return type, in the type of a template non-type parameter, or the type of a function parameter (with a default argument) Also, `do` is a keyword.

Comment: And the exact same mistake you made is given as an example of what not to do on cppreference